# Font size in Spring Tool Suite menu bar (Eclipse)

Tags: spring, eclipse

I would like to increase the font size of the Spring Tool Suite (eclipse) menu bar but I don't know where to modify this parameter. I have gone to

```
Window Menu -> Preferences -> General > Appearance > Color and Fonts > Basic > Text Font > Edit & Apply
```

But this does not change the font size of the menu bar:

[image]

Is it possible to change the font size of the menu bar?

Thanks

Comment: In your operating system (Eclipse does not render the menu widgets itself but uses for menus the native widgets of the operating system).

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts-> Basic -> Text Font

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to the directory where the spring tool suite resides
- select SpringToolSuite4.exe
- Click your right mouse bottom
- Click properties
- Click the compatibility tab
- Check overwrite high DPI scaling
- Click OK at the bottom

Comment: Thank your for your answer but the DPI scaling option doesn't increase the font size of the Spring Tool Suite (eclipse).